# Selection Sort from both ends with Min and Max Python

Tags: python, selection-sort

I need to implement a way to make a selection sort more efficient by working from both ends using min and max values.

I Have it working just using the index from the minimum value but I still need to find a way to work backward at the same time from the max.

```
def selectionsort(alist):

    for i in range(len(alist)): 

        min_idx = i 
        for j in range(i+1, len(alist)): 
            if alist[min_idx] > alist[j]: 
                min_idx = j 

        temp = alist[i]
        alist[i] = alist[min_idx]
        alist[min_idx] = temp

alist = [54,26,93,17,77,31,44,55,20]
selectionsort(alist)
print(alist)
```

The function should return the orderd list: [17, 20, 26, 31, 44, 54, 55, 77, 93]

Answer (score 0):

Keep track of the maximum value too & copy it to the end of the list - just like you're doing with minimum values.

```
def selection_sort(l):
    i = 0
    j = len(l) - 1
    while i < j:
        min_idx = i
        max_idx = i
        max_val = l[i]
        for k in range(i, j+1):
            if l[min_idx] > l[k]:
                min_idx = k
            if l[max_idx] < l[k]:
                max_idx = k
                max_val = l[k]

        l[i], l[min_idx] = l[min_idx], l[i]

        # Edge-case: if we shifted the value to the maximum in the last swap
        if l[min_idx] == max_val:
            l[j], l[min_idx] = l[min_idx], l[j]
        else:
            l[j], l[max_idx] = l[max_idx], l[j]

        i += 1
        j -= 1

    return l


my_list = [54, 26, 93, 17, 77, 31, 44, 55, 20]
my_list = selection_sort(my_list)
print(my_list)
```

Comment: Can you further explain the Edge-Case? What would be an instance where that would be used?